# Facebook not requesting signed_request on page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

This is my application on facebook page. 
https://www.facebook.com/SlcChallenge/app_439780382750381
Here my problem is that. Facebook sends signed_request for some user and does't returns 
from some user. So when facebook doesn't send signed request my page gets error.
my page tab url is https://tippll.com/pagetab.php/

Please help me to find the solution.
Thanks in advance
Krishna Karki

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If on canvas load you receive a `code` instead of a `signed_request`, this means that Facebook could not authenticate the user (and retrieve an `access_token`, and has fallen back to sending a code for you to exchange for an `access_token`.

Double-check your canvas URL settings in your facebook application. This can sometimes happen if you have URL rewriting non-SSL requests through to SSL domains (or even just url rewrites in general).

Comment: yea i have url rewriting on my htaccess. now what should i do to solve this?

Comment: The Canvas URL has to match the URL that facebook sends the user. In my case, I was rewriting users to the `https` url, although facebook was expecting an `http` url`. Because of the mismatch, the token could not be verified, and a `code` was sent instead.